# Converting netCDF to geotiff file?

Tags: gdal, netcdf

NetCDF files downloaded from [NASA ocean color website](https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODIS-Aqua/L2/) could not be converted to geotiff using gdaltranslate command below:

```
 gdal_translate -ot float32 -unscale -CO COMPRESS=deflate NETCDF:"A2006001170000.L2_LAC_OC.x.nc":chlor_a fulldisk.tif
```

The error message is the following:

```
Warning 1: NetCDF driver detected file type=5, but libnetcdf detected type=3
Warning 1: NETCDF:A2006001170000.L2_LAC_OC.x.nc:chlor_a is a netCDF file, but chlor_a is not a variable.
ERROR 4: `NETCDF:A2006001170000.L2_LAC_OC.x.nc:chlor_a' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```

Is there any way of fixing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
gdal_translate -ot float32 -unscale -CO COMPRESS=deflate HDF5:"A2006001170000.L2_LAC_OC.nc"://geophysical_data/chlor_a fulldisk.tif
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Related to this, is it possible to install netcdf for python on Windows? I am struggling with it.

Comment: I found out that the above script only shows the no data values for me. Could you please advice me what to do? I have tried A2006001170000.L2_LAC_OC.x.tif

Comment: @wondie As there is no chance `A2006001170000.L2_LAC_OC.x.tif` appears in the process, other than the case you specify it as an output filename, I suspect a typo error in your code. You may want to post your full code.

Comment: There is some improvement since the earlier post. Now, I am able to see the data but the image is inverted in GIS software. This is the file I am using now. https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/A2018001180000.L2_LAC_OC.nc I am using this updated code below. `"gdal_translate"  -ot float32 -unscale -co PROFILE=BASELINE -co COMPRESS=deflate -of GTiff -a_nodata -32767.0 -scale 0 100 HDF5:"A2018001180000.L2_LAC_OC.nc"://geophysical_data/chlor_a A2018001180000.L2_LAC_OC.tif `

Comment: @wondie Yes, it seems inverted to me, too. Remove `-co PROFILE=BASELINE` and see what happens.

Comment: the removal of `-co PROFILE=BASELINE` now makes the file to look normal but it is grascale in QGIS but it is stretched and distorted in ArcGIS and Seadas.

Comment: @wondie `-co PROFILE=BASELINE` removed geotags from GeoTiff. If it causes trouble with ArcGIS, then you can save a world file and set ArcGIS to use this world file by `Customize | ArcMap Options | Raster tab | Raster Dataset tab | Use world file to define the coordinates of the raster`. I cannot find info about Seadas.

Comment: I followed your steps but I didn't see any change. I also tried adding world file in the code using `-co "TFW=YES"` but I got this warning and no world file is created. `Warning 1: TFW=ON or WORLDFILE=ON creation options are ignored when GCPs are available`. If it works in ArcGIS, Seadas is not necessary. It is a software created by NASA to process ocean color data.

Comment: @wondie Try `-co WORLDFILE=YES` (Sorry, I really have to go sleep now). If you need support for ArcGIS please consider to post new question.

Comment: thank you! Please sleep. The wold file failed also with the above parameter. I will post a new question.

Comment: I have asked another question here. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286385/gdal-translate-creating-non-standard-file-from-netcdf