# Gdal Translate Creating Non-Standard File from netCDF

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I am trying to convert netCDF file from NASA Ocean Color website such as https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/A2018001180000.L2_LAC_OC.nc now the file converts fine using the answer to [Converting netCDF to geotiff file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284946).

Below is the code:

```
"gdal_translate"  -ot float32 -a_srs EPSG:4326  -co COMPRESS=deflate -of GTiff -a_nodata -32767.0 HDF5:"A2018001180000.L2_LAC_OC.nc"://geophysical_data/chlor_a A2018001180000.L2_LAC_OC.tif
```

However, the file created only displays in QGIS and it has the following limitations in QGIS and ArcGIS.

**QGIS** - The image displays fine but the minimum and maximum is wrong.

**ArcGIS and Geoserver** - the image is inverted and distorted.

Is there a way to have a geotiff file that works normally in all applications?

QGIS:
[image]

ArcGIS:
[image]

Geoserver:
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you're changing the output datatype but not scaling the values at all.  The answer you linked includes the "-unscale" argument

Comment: So do you mean `-unscale` will fix it?

Comment: I can't download your sample at the moment so I can't tell ya.  Try it and see.  I'm almost certain that you're truncating input data values by changing the output type without changing the underlying values themselves

Comment: Is there section of the above code that is truncating the values? The values are supposed to stay as they are though.

Comment: @gberard were you able to check the script?

Comment: I still can't seem to download the example image (or any from the nasa download portal, for that matter).  Have you tried adding `-unscale` yet?  Alternatively, try excluding  `-ot float32`.  You can't just change the output datatype without rescaling the values to a range appropriate for that datatype.  Imagine I have an image of 16-bit unsigned integers (range 0-65535), and then I tell GDAL that it's actually 8-bit unsigned (0-255).  If I don't scale the input range to the output, then any values >255 are going to overflow.  GDAL won't do that scaling unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: Ok I have uploaded one file on dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/m52zu1czxieh9zm/A2018001180000.L2_LAC_OC.nc?dl=1 I tried both but didn't work.

Comment: Your original command works fine...  https://i.imgur.com/FhDC3XU.png

Comment: Oh I see! That is a nice tip. However, the image is abnormally stretched on the right side from top to bottom. Also not very visible but there is a stretching on the left bottom side

Comment: I got a solution finally! Thank you @gberard on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gdal code below is creating a georeferenced and valid Geotiff file. A vrt file needs to be created using gdal_translate first. Then that file needs to be converted to geotiff using gdalwarp.

```
gdal_translate -r cubic -of VRT -co COMPRESS=deflate -unscale -a_nodata -32767.0 -a_srs EPSG:4326  HDF5:"A2018001180000.L2_LAC_OC.nc"://geophysical_data/chlor_a  A2018001180000.L2_LAC_OC.vrt

gdalwarp -of GTIFF -tps  A2018001180000.L2_LAC_OC.vrt  A2018001180000.L2_LAC_OC.tif
```

This is how it looks now in geoserver with style.

[image]